# How to set (increase) java heap size in Octave 4.0.0?

Tags: java, octave, heap-memory

I got an error

```
error: [java] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

when using Java in Octave 4.0.0.

I googled and all the sources basically tell ([here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/function/javamem.html), for example) that I should change the `java.opts` file in the folder `OCTAVE_HOME/share/octave/OCTAVE_VERSION/m/java/`. I have found this folder, but the file `java.opts` is not there.

Comment: When a file is not present, that means it just uses whatever is default. If you want to change that, and the file does not exist, just create it.

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Comment: @carandraug Should I ask here how to set JVM version that Octave uses (currently it's 32 bit which does not allow for big enough heaps)?

Comment: that's a build option. I'm not even sure that question fits well on stack overflow or if you should ask on the octave help mailing list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an options configuration file does not exist, most programs use the default options. Create the file and then follow the instructions to include the needed change.